# How to wrap a C function whose parameter is wchar_t pointer with cython

Tags: pointers, cython

I want to use cython to wrap a C library. One function in the library is like

```
int hid_get_manufacturer_string(hid_device *device, wchar_t *string, size_t maxlen);
```

There are two questions:

1. What can I do with the `wchar_t` in cython;
2. How to convert the string pointer in my .pyx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare wchar_t:

```
cdef extern from "stddef.h":
    ctypedef void wchar_t
```

Or import from libc module:

```
from libc.stddef cimport wchar_t
```

A function to convert wchar_t to python string by using WideCharToMultiByte (see [CefStringToPyString](http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/utils.pyx#205)):

```
# Declare these in .pxd file:
#
# cdef extern from "Windows.h":
#     cdef int CP_UTF8
#     cdef int WideCharToMultiByte(int, int, wchar_t*, int, char*, int, char*, int*)

cdef object WideCharToPyString(wchar_t *wcharstr):
    cdef int charstr_bytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wcharstr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)
    # Do not use malloc, otherwise you get trash data when string is empty.
    cdef char* charstr = <char*>calloc(charstr_bytes, sizeof(char))
    cdef int copied_bytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wcharstr, -1, charstr, charstr_bytes, NULL, NULL)
    if bytes == str:
        pystring = "" + charstr # Python 2.7
    else:
        pystring = (b"" + charstr).decode("utf-8", "ignore") # Python 3
    free(charstr)
    return pystring
```

Since Python 3.2 you can do this with the use of PyUnicode_FromWideChar(wcharstr, -1), see the comment by compostus.

Comment: Thanks Czarek Tomczak for your answer. But after I do what you tell me to, there comes an error: Name 'wchar_t' not declared in module 'stddef'. After I check the stddef.pxd, I think it just change wchar_t into int. So can I do the same thing in my .pxd file.

Comment: @Dewey, ahh I got this local stddef.pxd file in which I define wchar_t: "ctypedef void wchar_t". Edited answer.

Comment: @Dewey: I've edited my answer again to add declarations of CP_UTF8 and WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: JFYI: since Python 3.2 you can use [PyUnicode_FromWideChar(wcharstr, -1)](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_FromWideChar), see example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521011/cython-convert-wide-string-wchar-t-to-python-3-unicode-object/).